# Wamp no inicia por algún problema de accesos

Tags: mysql, wamp

Wamp no inicia y el icono se queda en rojo (lo ejecuté como administrador aunque ya lo hace por default) lo que indica que ningún servicio ha iniciado. Al iniciarlos individualmente en el menú de wamp me aparece este error :

```
Could not excecute menu item (internal error)[Exception] Could not perform service actions:
```

Acceso denegado.

**No es un problema de puertos** porque al probarlos me aparece tanto el puerto 80 libre como 3306 y 3307 para apache, mysql y mariadb respectivamente, incluso cambiando los puertos a otros igualmente libres. He verificado que los puertos que ocupe estén libres con `netstat -aon` lo que lista los puertos ocupados.

He reinstalado los 3 servicios desde el menú de wamp. Y sigue apareciendo el mismo error al intentar iniciarlos individualmente.

Un error similar aparece al iniciar apache por consola (consola ejecutada como administrador)

```
net start wapapache "Error de sistema 5. Acceso denegado." . 
net start wampmysqld net start wampmariadb no se reconocen.
```

También he intentado iniciarlos en el administrador de servicios de windows y aparece el error:

```
"Windows no pudo iniciar el servicios wampapache en Equipo local. Error 5: Acceso denegado.
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: seguramente tienes skype, por alguna razon skype ocupa el puerto 80 cierra skype e intenta levantar el servicio

Comment: Por favor lee bien la pregunta, he comentado que no es un problema de puertos y es de acceso además comenté que he verificado que el puerto 80 esta libre, no tengo skype instalado.

Comment: y el log de wamp que te dice?

Comment: Ah mira por ahí puede haber un problema, dice: 
[18-Apr-2019 15:37:56 UTC] Apache variable '${INSTALL_DIR}' is not defined.
 May be Apache service 'wampapache' is not started.

Pero ya me fui a httpd-vhosts.conf y la puse manualmente, no funcionó.

Comment: revisa el httpd.conf las lineas esas `Define INSTALL_DIR tu_ruta` y 
`Define APACHE_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}`

Comment: Intenté hacer eso pero no me dejaba guardar el archivo así que pensé que era un problema en los permisos de la carpeta de wamp y resultó que sí, por alguna razón no estaban asignados al sistema por eso me decía Acceso denegado. Solamente los reasigne en propiedades de la carpeta / seguridad, añadí SYSTEM y todo volvió a funcionar. Gracias.